# How to return the average value using fastapi & pydantic

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I am new to fasts-api and python as I am a mobile developer.

At the moment I managed to get this response from my API (please look at `averageLevel` which is an array at the moment):

```
[
  {
    "user_id": 139,
    "event_date": "2023-03-20T12:18:17",
    "public": 1,
    "waitlist": 1,
    "maxParticipant": 9,
    "event_type": "1 vs 1",
    "event_field": "Acrylic",
    "event_id": 173,
    "created": "2023-03-20T13:18:05",
    "organizer": {
      "user_id": 139,
      "email": "email@email.com",
      "name": "Daniele",
      "lastName": "Proietti",
      "city": "Rome",
      "state": "Lazio",
      "zipCode": " 32323",
      "country": "Italy",
      "averageLevel": [
        {
          "level": 70
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

The table that holds the player's level values is the following:

[image]

my models.py:

```
class Event(Base):
    __tablename__ = "event"
    event_id = Column(_sql.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(_sql.Integer, ForeignKey("users.user_id", ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=False, index=True, nullable=False)
    sport_id = Column(_sql.Integer, ForeignKey("sportSupported.sport_id"), primary_key=False, index=True, nullable=False)
    place_id = Column(_sql.Integer, ForeignKey("places.place_id"), primary_key=False, index=True, nullable=False)
    created = Column(_sql.DateTime(), default=datetime.now(), nullable=True)
    event_date = Column(_sql.DateTime(), nullable=False)
    public = Column(_sql.Integer, default = 0)
    waitlist = Column(_sql.Integer, default = 0)
    event_type = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    event_field = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    description = Column(String(255), nullable=True)
    maxParticipant = Column(_sql.Integer, nullable=False)
    player_level =  Column(_sql.Float, default= 0.0, nullable=False)
    organizer = relationship("User")
    participants = relationship("User", secondary=association_table)
    venue = relationship("Place", back_populates="event")


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    password = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    salt = Column(String(255),nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(50),nullable=False)
    lastName = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    dob = Column(DateTime(), nullable=True)
    city = Column(String(50), nullable=True)
    state = Column(String(40),nullable=True)
    zipCode = Column(String(10), nullable=True)
    country = Column(String(90), nullable=True)
    telephoneNumber = Column(String(60))
    joined = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.now(), nullable=False)
    facebook_id = Column(Integer)
    verified = Column(Integer, default = 0, nullable=False)
    testAccount = Column(Integer, default = 0, nullable=False)
    averageLevel = relationship("PlayersLevel")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.user_id}"

class PlayersLevel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "playersLevel"
    prog_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey("users.user_id", ondelete="CASCADE"),primary_key=False, index=True, nullable=False)
    event_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    date = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.now(), nullable=False)
    level = Column(Integer)
    sport_id = Column(Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.progr_id}"
```

and schema.py:

```
class User(BaseClass):
    user_id: int
    email: str
    name: str
    lastName: str
    city: str
    state: str
    zipCode: str
    country: str
    averageLevel: list[PlayersLevel] = []


class PlayersLevel(BaseClass):
    proper_id: int
    user_id: int
    event_id: int
    date: datetime
    level: int
    sport_id: int

class EventRead(Event):
    event_id: int
    created: datetime
    organizer: User
    participants: list[User] = []
    venue: Place
```

I query the database like this (all events):

```
def get_events(db: Session):
     return db.query(models.Event).all()
```

However, what I would like to achieve is the average of all level rows for a specific `user_id` (not an array of levels as it is now): something like this:

```
[
  {
    "user_id": 139,
    "event_date": "2023-03-20T12:18:17",
    "public": 1,
    "waitlist": 1,
    "maxParticipant": 9,
    "event_type": "1 vs 1",
    "event_field": "Acrylic",
    "event_id": 173,
    "created": "2023-03-20T13:18:05",
    "organizer": {
      "user_id": 139,
      "email": "mattiamauceri@gmail.com",
      "name": "Daniele",
      "lastName": "Proietti",
      "city": "Rome",
      "state": "Lazio",
      "zipCode": " 32323",
      "country": "Italy",
      "averageLevel": // not an array here 
        {
          "level": 74 // if there are 3 rows for the user (70, 72, 80) I would like to get the average IE 74
        }
      
    }
  }
]
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want that average to be calculated on the Pydantic model or by the ORM itself? Because right now your `User` table mapper class defines `averageLevel` as a simple relationship to the `playersLevel` table, which results in a collection of associated `PlayersLevel` instances on that field. This is semantically questionable. But you _could_ leave that as is (maybe rename that relationship to `levels` or so) and just calculate the average on the Pydantic model during initialization. Depends on what you need.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg  Thnk you so much! it's ok to calculate the average on the  Pydantic model. How can I achieve that? I was looking at `@property` but didn't achieve what I wanted! Thanks again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom [root validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#root-validators) with `pre=True` on the user model to check, if a list of levels was passed and calculate the average from those.

Here is a simplified example:

```py
from collections.abc import Mapping
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel as PydanticBaseModel, root_validator


class BaseModel(PydanticBaseModel):
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class UserModel(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    avg_level: float

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def calc_from_levels(cls, values: Mapping[str, Any]) -> dict[str, Any]:
        values = dict(values)
        lvl_objects = values.get("levels")
        if values.get("avg_level") is not None or not lvl_objects:
            return values
        values["avg_level"] = sum(
            obj.level for obj in lvl_objects
        ) / len(lvl_objects)
        return values


class EventModel(BaseModel):
    id: int
    organizer: UserModel
```

Note that this implementation assumes the relevant key in the provided data is named **`levels`**. If you want to stick with your name `averageLevel` (which I would not recommend because it is misleading) or name it something else on your ORM class, you need to adjust the `lvl_objects = values.get("levels")` line in the validator method accordingly. That is where the list is extracted.

Also notice that this implementation still allows `avg_level` to be set *explicitly*. If that key is present, the validator will *not even attempt to look* for the levels list. Likewise, if no levels list was provided (or it is empty), nothing else happens in this validator, which means that will likely cause a validation error further down the line because I defined `avg_level` as **required** (no default).

Just some dumb data calasses to test:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class PlayerLevel:
    level: int

@dataclass
class User:
    id: int
    name: str
    levels: list[PlayerLevel]

@dataclass
class Event:
    id: int
    organizer: User

mock_db_event = Event(
    id=123,
    organizer=User(
        id=1,
        name="foo",
        levels=[
            PlayerLevel(70),
            PlayerLevel(72),
            PlayerLevel(80),
        ]
    ),
)

event = EventModel.from_orm(mock_db_event)
print(event.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
{
    "id": 123,
    "organizer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "foo",
        "avg_level": 74.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am getting the following error when I query all events: `pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 4 validation errors for EventRead
response -> 0 -> organizer -> avg_level
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> 1 -> organizer -> avg_level
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> 2 -> organizer -> avg_level
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> 3 -> organizer -> avg_level
  field required (type=value_error.missing)` Please note that I have 4 events in the database

Comment: Have you modified the validator so that it actually grabs your levels list as I explained?

Comment: it was an indentation problem!!! It works perfectly!!! THANKS